# Add table data from sql server to text file with select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to export a table present in ms sql server 2017 to a text file on my system. I am writing the following command in sql server query window

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Input
INTO OUTFILE 'C\filename.txt'
```

Now I write this command the sql help gives me error that

> incorrect syntax near 'INTO'

Then I tried to new query

```sql
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\filename.txt'
FROM Input
```

Now it gives me error that

> incorrect syntax near 'C:/filename.csv'

Please help me regarding this. I am not able to remove these error and get a working sql

Comment: You *can't* `INTO` a file; if you need to export data to a text (csv?) file, then you need to be using something else; not T-SQL. Either use an ETL tool, or a scripting or programming language (which is up to you).

Comment: You'll either have to copy it manually or using something like python or SSIS to extract and save to a text file.
You could even extract the data using MS Excel with a data connecter

Comment: Powershell does this nicely `Invoke-DbaQuery -Query "SELECT * FROM Input" -SqlInstance ...... -As DataTable | Export-Csv "YourFile" -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the data from the db and insert it into the .txt file using the php fopen() function to append/write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you need:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/

Also CLR may be a solution (not high recommended thought), because you will write code in vb or C# and it will  be converted to SQL Stored procedure/Function.

Comment: Don't you have to be sysadmin or have it enabled by one to be run that?

Comment: You need to enable and use the proxy account, if you mean for the first solution of mine.